# SQL Server : Linked Server Querying

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Sorry if this is a newbie question.

Situation : I have a local SQL Server linked to a main SQL Server (reason, I don't have access to create views/sps/etc on main server)

I have defined `views1`, `views2`, `views3` on local SQL Server which entirely relates tables/views on the main server (NO local SQL Server tables)

Q: how will a join on `view1` and `view2` or `view3` materialize? That is, will the results of each view be pulled into the local server and joined locally (even though all referenced tables are on the main server)? Are there any guarantees one way or the other, OR is it entirely up to the optimizer ?

Q: if the view referenced a UDF on the local server, [ how ] would the process above change ?

Many thanks.

Comment: Views don't materialize (unless you place indexes on the view).  This does not sound like a good game plan to me.

Comment: Have described what i mean by materialise. As in, are joins performed locally after pulling the data from the linked server.

Comment: If you want materialize to mean something other than materialize then use another word.

Comment: I agree wit Blam... this is probably not the best solution. If you really need this data for future development have you thought about using some sort of an ETL process to bring the data in locally?

Comment: Conceptually, I see your point. But since i know the dataset/size ( less than 1 million records) and how often i have to pull it, on a 1G local network, for this case it suits to pull on demand without transient stores. Thanks. FYI it works nicely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all the tables involved in the query are on the same remote server (and that server is an Microsoft SQL Server), the JOIN operation should be performed remotely. To find out if it is executed locally or remotely, you can look at the execution plan (it should contain only a "Remote Query", no joins) or use Profiler on the remote server (if you have sufficient rights).

If the JOIN operation is perfomed locally, you may be able to change the query plan if you use the REMOTE JOIN hint (although this hint only makes sense if one of the tables is a local one). Getting an efficient query plans depends on having updated statistics and in the case of a distributed query (joining a local table to a remote table), this also means having enough rights to read the remote statistics: "If the linked server is an instance of SQL Server, to obtain all available statistics, the user must own the table or be a member of the sysadmin fixed server role, the db_owner fixed database role, or the db_ddladmin fixed database role on the linked server".

Comment: REMOTE JOIN hunt will work for local server UDF? Using only MsSql servers

Comment: When the REMOTE hint is used in a JOIN of two local tables, it has no effect except enforcing the order of the joins (like any other JOIN hint), an effect similar to using `OPTION (FORCE ORDER)` (therefore probably producing a sub-optimal plan), as the warning says "Warning: The join order has been enforced because a local join hint is used."